# How to save paint-brush drawings drawn over images as a filled and separate binary mask in opencv?

Tags: opencv, python-3.5, mask

In the openCV tutorials there's this ["mouse as a paintbrush" tutorial](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_mouse_handling/py_mouse_handling.html#mouse-handling) that demonstrates how to draw on an image. I know how to save the result with the imwrite function, but how do I save only the drawn and filled contour and save it as a black and white binary mask?

First, I have an image:

[image]

Next,I draw on it with my mouse following the "mouse as a paintbrush" tutorial. Which results in this:

[image]

No, I want to separate the original image and my sketch to obtain this:

[image]

and this is what I want to save to file.

There's no codes to upload because the mask (third pic) that I have right now is not obtained from the sketch. It is from mask annotations. My problem now is, how do I separate the user's sketch as a separate layer from the original Image? I tried to look around for answers but it seems like there's mostly only merging functions instead of separating them.

Should I use external libraries like Cairo? I'm trying to do this in Python 3.5. Please advise and any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please show your code that produces these images. The code you linked to appears to draw either circles or rectangles but this doesn't look like either!

Comment: The link shows how to draw continuous circles and so by using a small circle size and continuously dragging the mouse around it'll result in a simple drawing application. I didn't upload the codes that produced these images because I felt like it was irrelevant to my question because I essentially wanted to know how I can save image overlay-ed sketches as separate mask images. These images were obtained through a method that is not relevant to the task at hand. They're just rough examples but I appreciate your comments :)

Comment: Hi @MarkSetchell, unfortunately, it didnt...I don't want to merge, I'd want to split a drawn image.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated Again**

You absolutely can create an alpha channel and add it to your image. It could look like this:

```
# Split image into its three constituent channels, R, G and B
R, G, B = cv2.split(image)

# Make a same-shape alpha channel, initially opaque (255)
alpha   = np.ones_like(R)*255

# Merge R, G, B and alpha into a 4-channel image
imgwithalpha = cv2.merge((R, G, B, alpha))
```

The only issue will be that OpenCV'S `imshow()` ignores alpha, whilst `imwrite()` honours alpha and saves it to disk. So I would paint the mask in red like you have (so the user can see it) but at the same time also save a mask in black and white. Then, at the end, merge the black and white in as an alpha channel as shown above - black where you want transparency, and white where you want opacity.

**Updated Answer**

So, it looks like your code is somewhat different from the OpenCV example code and you are actually loading a different image rather than the black  one they use. No matter, make a black image the same size as your bird (using numpy `zeros_like(bird)`. Then, when you draw on the bird, draw the same curcle in white on the black copy. At the end, use `floodFill()` with (0,0) as the seed to fill in all the area outside the bird on the black image and save it as below.

**Original Answer**

I am not sure I understand your question, so I'll answer what I think you are asking and see if that leads to the right solution.

The code you link to creates an empty black canvas 512x512 like this:

```
img = np.zeros((512,512,3), np.uint8)
```

It then draws circles on it each time you click the mouse. So, you just need to save that image just before you exit. So, add this as the last line:

```
cv2.imwrite('mask.png',img)
```

Comment: I'm sorry...I think my question was really badly phrased. Maybe I'll try to rephrase and edit my question. Thanks a lot for trying to help me!!

Comment: I have updated my answer in the light of your revised question.

Comment: Thanks for updating, but I want to avoid doing that that's why I'm asking. Like I would rather have like a transparent layer over the original image and let the user draw on the transparent layer and save the transparent layer. I guess its not possible to do this in openCV...

Comment: Ok, I have updated my answer again. Please have another look.